# Resizing the unity launcher bar 15.10

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

Is there a way on Ubuntu 15.10 to resize the actual Unity 'bar' to reflect the amount of icons that are present? Similar to Docky but with the default Unity bar?

Cheers.

Sort of like this:

[image]

Comment: Similar to the way OSX handles this?

Comment: Basically yeah, just resizing the Unity bar based on how many icons are on it, I'd ideally like it to be centred also. I've edited my original post with an 'image' of what I mean

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarification!

No, you cannot do that with the *default* dock, however if you install the Cairo Dock, you can do this, and much more.

It is available in the default Ubuntu repos, so you can just install it from the Software Center. The How-To-Geek has an extensive guide for installing and customizing it.

http://www.howtogeek.com/201123/how-to-install-and-use-a-mac-os-x-style-desktop-dock-in-ubuntu-14.04/